# Show form of all features visible in map in a QGIS GUI

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-table

I have forms defined on my layer, I have a HTML widget in it that displays some HTML derived from a feature attribute.

[image]

Through attribute table above I can view form of visible features one by one but there is no way to view forms of all of them together. Basically my use case is such that I want to look at the HTML to identify features, so for example if on the left side of the above image I could see HTML in place of 10, 21, 22. I can identify feature I want to select.

Therefore I am looking for a way to display form of all features visible on the map. I tried putting HTML in a field but the left side pane of the above image do not display HTML.

I am open to external plugin or python solutions.